# Jasper PDF Export Issue as Columns Exceeds page width

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 25 columns to export to pdf, When I'm exporting I can see only 10 columns. Is there any way to set any properties to see all the 25 columns when export to pdf?
If page width is less, then it should print the remaining columns in the next page.
Requirement is to take prints on A4 Size paper of all the columns in the report.